# Where can I find keras' losses.py?

Tags: anaconda, keras

I want to define my own loss, but I can't find the file. I'm running keras on Ananconda using python2.7 on linux. Is there a way I can check the directory of losses.py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first write it in your terminal (verify you are using anaconda):

```
which python
```

if you are using anaconda, go to anaconda directory, Keras *should* be here:

```
~/anaconda2/pkgs/keras-2.0.5-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras$
```

and the **losses.py** is also there.